# How to adjust radio listening time in cooja simulator (Radio duty cycle)

Tags: networking, iot, ns-3, cooja

I am using contiki version 2.7. One of the things I want to do is to keep the motes on for 2 seconds after waking up and if there is no data flow, turn off their radio and go to sleep mode again. If there is a data flow, I want to ensure that the motes that send data turn off their radio immediately after they are finished. I want to eliminate their constant listening, I can provide this. I couldn't find many resources on the internet, I would be glad if you could help. I tried a few things but no successful results.
I adjust the code but it is not working

Comment: PROCESS_THREAD(slip_radio_process, ev, data)
{
static struct etimer sleep_timer;
static int data_received = 0;
PROCESS_BEGIN();
init();
NETSTACK_RDC.off(1);
\#ifdef SLIP_RADIO_CONF_SENSORS
SLIP_RADIO_CONF_SENSORS.init();
\#endif
printf("Slip Radio started...\\n");
while(1) {
NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_POWER_MODE, RADIO_POWER_MODE_OFF);
PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT();
if (ev == PROCESS_EVENT_CONTINUE) {
NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_POWER_MODE, RADIO_POWER_MODE_ON);
data_received = 0;

Comment: Please don't add comments for additional information. Code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. Also be more precise: what do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].